# Коллеги помогите с вопросом по микросервисам. Не могу понять как использовать сущность в другом микросервисе

Tags: java, spring, микросервисы

Всем привет. Начинаю разбираться как писать микросервисы и решил переписать интернет магазин. Создал первый микросервис, который содержит сущности (продукты), репозиторий, сервис, контроллер и второй, который содержит сущности (заказы) и весь оставшийся набор. У каждого своя база. Использую java, Spring boot, discovery eureka, feign client
Сущность заказа состоит из id, List, OrderItem состоял раньше из Product (при монолите). Вопрос в том, что я не могу понять как теперь использовать cущность product в другом микросервисе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, сам алгоритм, как это сделать
Заранее благодарю за любой ответ.

Comment: Поставил себе задачу: разделить на два микросервиса заказы и продукты и сохранять каждого в своей базе

Comment: Что именно нужно сделать сильно зависит от того, что именно от сущности продукт нужно в сервисе заказов. Но обычно с заказах нужно создать свою сущность продукт, в которой будут только данные нужные заказам, в БД ее скорее всего не хранить и получать через вызов к МС продукты. В заказе в БД хранить только идентификатор продукта.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, буду дальше разбираться как сделать